# Order (sub-)categories in Doctrine with Symfony2/YML

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've finally succeeded to create a working self-referencing relationship in Doctrine/Symfony2. But, when I request a findAll the table rows aren't returned in the order I want. (Maybe it's not THAT easy, but I can't find any solution anymore.)

### The table "categories"

```
id    parentId    name
1     NULL         music
2     NULL         films
3     1            bands
4     1            guitars
5     NULL         books
6     2            actors
```

### The file "category.orm.yml"

```
FormBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    oneToMany:
        children:
            fetch: "EAGER"
            targetEntity: FormBundle\Entity\Category
            mappedBy: parent
            cascade: ["all"]
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: FormBundle\Entity\Category
            inversedBy: children
            joinColumn:
                name: parentId
                referencedColumnName: id
    table: categories
    repositoryClass: FormBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository
    id:
        id:
            column: id
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: '100'
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I tried an orderBy (in any way I could find, on any field) but I haven't succeeded or had ANY progress with it.

### The entity file "Category.php"

```
<?php

namespace FormBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var category
     */
    private $parent;


    /**
     * @var arrayCollection
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getChildren() {
        return $this->children;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set parentId
     *
     * @param integer $parentId
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParent(Category $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parentId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

### What I want as output

```
<b>music</b>
bands
guitars
<b>films</b>
actors
<b>books</b>
```

This will be a list, but let's not worry about that right now! It's about the order!

### My question

What do I put in my controller to use the relations and fetch the rows in the order I want? Or even better; what do I put in the controller and the repository?

I don't want to use DQL since that is not how Doctrine is meant to be used. I want to learn Doctrine and this is seems to be a very good thing to learn. Yes, I have read the docs for a few days, but nothing seems to work for me. Maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: Doctrine is not meant to be used with DQL?  Never heard that one before.  DQL (Doctrine Query Language) is a core component of Doctrine.

Comment: @Cerad I knew that was going to be misunderstood, haha. But I didn't know a better way to say it. (Still find English a little difficult) DQL is indeed a part of Doctrine. But with DQL I don't think you're using the full capacity of Doctrine, at least not how Doctrine represents itself. It will always remain a key element of course. But on to productiveness and my question... Do you have a solution or something to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Okay.  Guess we will leave DQL aside.  There are some Doctrine tree bundles out there.  Might research one of them.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I saw a few bundles but thought that if I declared the relationship it should be somewhat natural to order it not like without the relations declared. But I'll look into them and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree depth will likely be > 1, [Doctrine extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) with his Tree-NestedSet will be a good pick. If it's not the case, your question becomes trivial :

In your controller :

```
$parentCategories = $categoryRepository->findBy(array('parent' => null));
return $this->render('path_to_your_view.html.twig', array(
    'parentCategories' => $parentCategories
));
```

In your view :

```
{% for parentCategory in parentCategories %}
    <b>{{ parentCategory.getName() | e }}</b>
    {% for childCategory in parentCategory.getChildren() %}
        <p>{{ childCategory.getName() | e }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using extensions if possible, but this seems to be the only solution, except for using a recursive twig template for the questions. The example given in this answer however produces the output requested and thus it's the accepted answer. Thanks!